# get the view coordinate in a point sprite

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

If you pass a *varying* view-space position from the vertex shader to a fragment shader then the fragment shader can know the fragment's position relative to the camera (`0,0,0` in view-space).  This is useful for per-pixel lighting etc.  E.g.:

```
precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 vertex;
uniform mat4 pMatrix, mvMatrix;
varying vec4 pos;
void main() {
    pos = (mvMatrix * vec4(vertex,1.0));
    gl_Position = pMatrix * pos;
}
```

However, if you are rendering `gl_POINTS` and setting the `gl_PointSize` in the vertex shader, how can the fragment shader determine each fragment's position (as the `pos` passed in the example above will be for the sprite's centre-point)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: *stop using point sprites.* Really, they're terrible.

Less simple answer: stop passing the view-space position to the fragment shader entirely. Instead, use `gl_FragCoord` to [compute the view-space position, based on viewport data and so forth](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space). There's even sample GLSL code for it:

```
vec4 ndcPos;
ndcPos.xy = ((2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy) - (2.0 * viewport.xy)) / (viewport.zw) - 1;
ndcPos.z = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.z - gl_DepthRange.near - gl_DepthRange.far) /
    (gl_DepthRange.far - gl_DepthRange.near);
ndcPos.w = 1.0;

vec4 clipPos = ndcPos / gl_FragCoord.w;
vec4 eyePos = invPersMatrix * clipPos;
```

You'll need to give your fragment shader the `viewport` and `invPersMatrix` values. `gl_DepthRange` is built-in. `eyePos` is what you're looking for.

There's probably a faster way to do it that takes advantage of the fact that you're drawing a screen-aligned quad. It would involve the point size and using `gl_PointCoord`.

Comment: This is completely spot on and accepted.  I had been trying to get something using point size and `gl_PointCoord` to work, and am very glad of this proper approach.  But can you elaborate on why point sprites are terrible?

Comment: @Will: Well, let's see. 1) They clip against the viewport with the center of the sprite, thus causing them to *disappear* when the center goes off-screen. 2) The problem you just encountered: interpolating parameters across a point sprite is a big pain. 3) They can only be window-space squares, so if you need scaled particles or whatever, you have to move to quads anyway.